# My button is not clickable on the text or icon, but is around it

Tags: html, css, typescript

I have a button with an icon and text under it. It is only clickable around the icon and text, but not on them.

[image: example]

scss file

```
.navbar {
  background-color: #292929;
 height: 70px;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  color: white !important;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px;  
}

.bx {
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.icon {
  flex: 1;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

/* Add hover effect to the button */
.button:hover .text, 
.button:hover .bx {
  color: red;
}
```

html

```
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
      <div class="navbar-start">
        <!-- Button on the left side -->
        <button class="button" (click)="logInfo()">
          <span class="icon">
            <i class='bx bx-file-find'></i>
          </span>
          <a href="#" class="text">Scan</a>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-end">
        <!-- Text on the far right side -->
        <div class="navbar-item is-size-5 has-text-white">test</div>
        <img src="assets/favicon.ico" />
      </div>
    </nav>
```

I added padding and margin,pointer-events: none, but this didn't work.
Changed the display to block but this causes the text to move on the right side of the icon.
I tried to use a differend icon and z-index:999; but this was not the solution.

Comment: Maybe your click isn't bubbling up when you click the child elements? You could try to figure that out or set `button > * { pointer-events: none; }` to prevent them from receiving your click.

Comment: Please first correct your HTML. You may not have an anchor element inside a button element. See for example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: @A Haworth thank you for pointing that out to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be no Interactive content inside a button element. That means the `<a>` tag is not permitted to be inside your button and this is breaking your page.
Remove the anchor tag and your button will work fine.
If you want your button to scroll to top you can add `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` to the `logInfo` function being called on the click of the button.

```
<button class="button" (click)="logInfo()">
  <span class="icon">
    <i class='bx bx-file-find'></i>
  </span>
  <span class="text">Scan</span>
</button>
```